# NAudio change volume in runtime

Tags: naudio

I would like change the volume of my audiostream in runtime.
I use this code:
Public Volume as Single = 0.01
    Dim Wave1 As New NAudio.Wave.WaveOut

```
Dim xa() As Byte = IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\Song - Come Out and Play.wav")

Sub PlaySound()

    Dim data As New IO.MemoryStream(xa)

    Wave1.Init(New NAudio.Wave.BlockAlignReductionStream(NAudio.Wave.WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(New NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(data))))

    Wave1.Volume = Volume

    Wave1.Play()

End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PlaySound()
End Sub
```

But how can i change the Volume in runtime?
It doesn´t change, when i click a button with

```
Volume = 2.0
```

Why?

Thanks for this.

Second problem: How must i change this code, to play MP3 instead of WAV?
Because WAV is to large..

Thanks for both :)

Sorry for my bad English.

Regards, René :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question about volume was answered by Mark - Volume is in the range `0.0 <= volume <= 1.0`, so setting the volume to 2.0 is invalid.

As to how to use MP3 files...

You can replace the `WaveFileReader` with `Mp3FileReader` in your code if the data you are feeding in is MP3 instead of WAV.  If the data is always coming from a file you could use `new AudioFileReader(filename)` instead and let it work out what the compression format is.

Here's your code with MP3 instead of WAV:

```
Public Volume as Single = 0.01

Dim Wave1 As New NAudio.Wave.WaveOut

Dim xa() As Byte = IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\Song - Come Out and Play.mp3")

Sub PlaySound()

    Dim data As New IO.MemoryStream(xa)

    Wave1.Init( _
        New NAudio.Wave.BlockAlignReductionStream( _
            NAudio.Wave.WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream( _
                New NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader(data) _
        )))

    Wave1.Volume = Volume

    Wave1.Play()

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PlaySound()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it works brilliant! But Volume = 0.9 doesnt change the volume in runtime :(

Answer (score 0):

The volume property has  a maximum value of 1.0 which indicates 1.0. The latest NAudio will throw an exception if you try to set it any higher.

Comment: But Volume = 0.9 doesnt change the volume in runtime :(

Comment: @user3052442 You can use the `VolumeSampleProvider` to change the volume. You could also make your own `ISampleProvider` and manipulate the floating point data directly on `Read(float[], int, int)` to eke out a bit more performance with `unsafe` and vectorisation.